# Remote Desktop Connection loses connect on websites | Hyper V installed

Tags: windows-server-2008, vps, hyper-v

I use RDC to connect to my dedicated server that is running Hyper V for VPSs. On the main dedicated I will visit certain sites, ex. Microsoft site, Chrome site. Those are just some, RDC will freeze and I have to reconnect. I know this has to do with Hyper V because when I uninstalled it to test it stopped happening.

Comment: Can you ping the host that you are connecting to?  Do you lose IP connectivity at the same time?  Or is this simply a RDC disconnect?

Comment: We need more information, what other troubleshooting have you done? Is the system fully patched? How many VPSes are running when this happens? Is the system starved for resources?

Comment: Can you ping the host that you are connecting to?
Yes, just a disconnect of RDC.

what other troubleshooting have you done?
Reinstalled

Is the system fully patched?
Yes.

How many VPSes are running when this happens?
Doesnt even have to be running a VPS it is just with the Hyper V role installed.

Is the system starved for resources?
No, Plenty to go around.